# regular expression to add exception

Tags: regex, actionscript

I have a regular expression as

> [^><]

for not matching the start and close tags

But how can I use this regular expression to do the above checking with allowing only the bold tags like `<b>` and `</b>`

Thanks

Comment: Regular expressions are not a good solution for parsing html / xml. Use a proper parser instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: Strip all non-<b> `</?(?!b\s*>)[^>]+>` if the script supports assertions.

Answer (score 1):

As pswg states, [don't use regular expressions to parse (x|ht)ml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1).

That said, if you use a regular expression anyway, you will find stripping out *not* bold tags much easier using:

```
<\/?[^b]*?>
```

And simply replacing that with nothing like so: http://regex101.com/r/uY7eK3

Comment: Are all the tags single letter?

Comment: @sln YES! ALL YOUR TAGS ARE BELONG TO US. But seriously, fixed. I'm just not used to parsing html with regex.